# Angular 2 loop through a list with some delay

Tags: arrays, loops, angular, typescript

How do I loop through an array with some delay with Angular 2 and TypeScript?

I have an array,

```
students: Array<any> = [
    {
      name: "Alan"
    },
    {
      name: "Jake"
    },
    {
      name: "Harry"
    },
    {
      name: "Susan"
    },
    {
      name: "Sarah"
    },
    {
      name: "Esther"
    }
];
```

I want to loop through the list and display the names with a `2000ms` delay.

```
<div *ngFor="let student of students">
    {{student.name}}
</div>
```

doesn't work with a delay but is looping all at once.

Comment: set timeout before populating an array

Comment: @AlekseyL. can you illustrate?

Comment: do you want delay before adding whole list or before adding each item?

Comment: @AlekseyL. before adding each item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/MgJkFskZRp39FubSUbmH?p=preview)

```
export class App {
  name:string;

  students: Array<any> = [
    {
      name: "Alan"
    },
    {
      name: "Jake"
    },
    {
      name: "Harry"
    },
    {
      name: "Susan"
    },
    {
      name: "Sarah"
    },
    {
      name: "Esther"
    }
];

  constructor() {
    var timer = 0;
    this.$students = Observable.from([[], ...this.students])
    .mergeMap(x => Observable.timer(timer++ * 1000).map(y => x))
    .scan((acc, curr) => {acc.push(curr); return acc;});
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Just use `setTimeout`. For example (* not tested):

```
students: Array<any> = [ ];

populateArrayWithDelay():void{
    let people = [
        {
            name: "Alan"
        },
        {
            name: "Jake"
        },
        {
            name: "Harry"
        },
        {
            name: "Susan"
        },
        {
            name: "Sarah"
        },
        {
            name: "Esther"
        }
    ];
    for(let i = 0; i < people.length; i++){
        let student = people[i];
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.students.push(student);
        }, 2000*(i+1));
    }
}
```

Comment: setTimeout breaks Angular change detection.

Comment: @Kody 7, no it doesn't. At least not in angular 2

Comment: It will once you have lifecycle hooks. You shouldn't use setTimeout in Angular.

Comment: @Kody can you point to documentation regarding this? Here's explanation how `setTimeout` triggers change detection in angular 2 https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/01/zones-in-angular-2.html