# Angular 2 - pass delay to component animation as input parameter

Tags: angular, angular2-animation

I want to pass in the delay of a component's animation from the html eg:

html:

```
<circles[delay]="'10000ms'"></circles>
```

ts:

```
@Component({
   selector: 'circles',
   templateUrl: 'app/landing-page/subcomponents/circles.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['app/landing-page/subcomponents/circles.component.css'],
    animations: [
        trigger('flyIn', [
            state('in', style({ transform: 'translateY(0)', opacity: 1 })),
            transition('void => *', [
                style({ transform: 'translateY(-100%)', opacity: 0 }),
                animate("1000ms" + this.delay)
            ])
        ])
    ]
})

export class CirclesComponent {
   @Input() private delay: string;
```

However when I do that it gives this error:

> (SystemJS) Cannot read property 'delay' of undefined(…)

How can I pass in the delay to the component in html without causing this error?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @adamdport No I didn't. The only work around I could think of was to write seperate components and give them a different delay and that was more effort than it was worth.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use `this` in `this.delay` to refer to the current class, but you are doing this outside the class. Note that `@Component()` function is executed before you declare `class CirclesComponent`

This isn't very elegant but you could set a property on the `window` object when you want to set the delay

```
window.custom = {delay:'1000ms'}
```

Then in your animation, you could access it with `window.custom? window.custom.delay :

```
animate("1000ms" + (window.custom? window.custom.delay : ""))
```

Comment: Hmm yeah I wasn't sure it would be possible. This solution is an option. My other option is to create a different component for each different delay, which is only about 6 components (potentially a few more in the future) - I was just concerned it might have a performance impact with more components.

Comment: @Beniamino_Baggins I wouldn't create multiple copies of the same component with just this minor difference. It breaks the DRY (don't-repeat-yourself) principle and will make the app more difficult to manage.

Comment: Good point. Although, you are still setting that component's delay to '1000ms'. Can you explain how you can set a different delay for two of that same component?

Answer (score 0):

I might be a little bit late but this may help someone else.

```
// Define your animations
export const fadeInDelay =
  trigger('fadeInDelay', [
    transition('void => *', [
        style({ opacity: '0' }),
        animate('250ms {{delay}}ms ease-in')
      ],
      { params: { delay: 200 } } //Fallback value; else it could crash when no delay is passed
    )
  ]);
```

Load it into your component:

```
@Component({
  animations: [fadeInDelay]
})
export class Component {
  ...
}
```

Then you can use it in your template like this and control the delay for each animation:

```
<div [@fadeInDelay]="{value: '', params: { delay: 1000}}"></div>
<div [@fadeInDelay]="{value: '', params: { delay: 2000}}"></div>
<div [@fadeInDelay]></div> //using fallback
```

Don´t forget to pass the a value else it will not work.
I hope this helps!